# How to upload wepb images into wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I try to upload wepb images into my websites. But it repeatly shows some errors. I already tried many plugins like WebP Express, EWWW Image Optimizer,Short Pixel Image optimizer. It works well but it will affect my slider(slider revolution). So I want to upload webp images manual or some other image upload plugins. Please give me some tips to upload img. thank you..
Have a great day..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this code in your theme/child theme's functions.php file or create a simple plugin and add the following code:

```
function add_webp_to_upload_mimes( $upload_mimes ) { 
    $upload_mimes['webp'] = 'image/webp'; 
    return $upload_mimes; 
} 
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'add_webp_to_upload_mimes', 10, 1 );
```